# queryResultCache in Solr not appearing

Tags: caching, tomcat, solr

I've just picked up a Solr implementation as part of a project part-developed by a former colleague. I'm looking at tuning the caches, however the queryResultCache does not appear to be recognised by Solr, despite being configured in solrconfig.xml.

I've taken the relevant section from another working Solr build and yet it is still not listed in the stats.

Here's my solrconfig.xml extract:

```
<queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                 size="2048"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/>
```

When I access the stats page, the only caches listed are fieldValueCache and fieldCache, there is no documentCache either.

Is there somewhere else this can be overridden that I've missed? I'm on Solr 3.6.1 on Tomcat 7 on Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [queryResultCache in SOLR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295320/queryresultcache-in-solr)