# queryResultCache in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene

I am wondering if queryResultCache in solrconfig.xml caches anything blindly or only successfully handled results? That is I don't want to cache failed query's results.

Also I see some attribute called "autowarmCount" in the queryResultCache definition.

```
<queryResultCache
   class="solr.LRUCache"
   size="16384"
   initialSize="16384"
   autowarmCount="128"/>
```

Can I specify queries for auto warming up? Or can it figure out itself what queries to use?

Comment: Can anybody tell why my `queryResultCache` lookups are not increasing and `filterCache` lookups are increasing under a load test by hitting the same query again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queryResultCache will only store results from successfully handled results.

Yes you can specify the queries to use for the autowarming. From the [Solr Reference Guide on Caches](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Query+Settings+in+SolrConfig), please see the Query-Related Listeners section for details on how the queries can be specified when searchers are either frist created or newly created to replace an existing searcher in Solr.

Also please note that the following (also from the Reference Guide):

> When a new searcher is opened, the current searcher continues servicing requests while the new one auto-warms its cache. The new searcher uses the current searcher's cache to pre-populate its own.

Comment: If I may ask -- What is considered successfully handled results?

Comment: The result set from a query that executes without any exceptions.

Comment: @PaigeCook: could you also clarify whether the `queryResultCache`, contain all the results returned by main query(the `q` param) or it contains results prepared after all filter queries ? Otherwise how I can cache results before filtering by filter queries? (As otherwise the hitratio would be near to nothing, for my case)

Comment: According to the Solr Reference Guide on Caches that I linked to above. The `queryResultCache` is only storing items based on the query results, while the `filterCache` stores items based on the `fq` search parameter. So in your case, you should probably specify relevant `fq` parameters in your autowarming queries.